# Error appending select options with Jquery AJAX JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, select

Here is the first part of my JSON string returned (from POST response in Firebug)

```
{"d":"{\"companies\" : [{\"CompanyID\" : \"5\",\"CompanyName\" : \"(No Insurance Carrier)\"},{\"CompanyID\" : \"0\",\"CompanyName\" : \"(None Specified)\"},{\"CompanyID\" : \"72431\",\"CompanyName\" : \"A.M. Technologies, Inc./W.P. Hickman Systems\"},{\"CompanyID\" : \"72486\",\"CompanyName\" : \"AAA\"},...]}"}
```

Here is the script for pageLoad:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: strURL + "/GetCompanyNames",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'strApplicationName':'hidden', 'strAPIkey':'hidden'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
       var options = $("#ddlCompany").attr('options');
         $('option', $("#ddlCompany")).remove();
         $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select Company", "-1");
           $.each(msg.d, function(item) {
              options[options.length] = new Option(item.CompanyName, item.CompanyID);
        });
     },
     error: function() {
        alert("Failed to load Companies");
     }
  });
```

The error I get is "CompanyName is undefined". Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Do I need to get to the table in the msg.d first?

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: strURL + "/GetCompanyNames",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'strApplicationName':'hidden', 'strAPIkey':'hidden'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select Company", "-1");
                        window.alert(msg.d);
                        for (var i = 0; i <= msg.d.companies.length - 1; i++) {
                            $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options[$("#ddlCompany").get(0).options.length] = new Option(msg.d.companies[i].CompanyName, msg.d.companies[i].CompanyID);
                        }

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Failed to load Companies");
                    }
                });
```

I tried this as well, but companies is not found. The window alert displays the msg.d JSON perfectly.

so this shouldn't be necessary, but if I parse the result into JSON it works in Firefox, but not in IE? For example:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: strURL + "/GetCompanyNames",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'strApplicationName':'hidden', 'strAPIkey':'hidden'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d")) { msg = msg.d; }
                        var json = JSON.parse(msg);
                        $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select Company", "-1");
                        for (var i = 0; i <= json.companies.length - 1; i++) {
                            $("#ddlCompany").get(0).options[$("#ddlCompany").get(0).options.length] = new Option(json.companies[i].CompanyName, json.companies[i].CompanyID);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Failed to load Companies");
                    }
                });
```

Any ideas why this script would then hang in IE?

Comment: I must be missing something, did you say that your msg will be equivalent to `{companies: [{...}]}` ?  What is the `msg.d` in your loop all about?

Answer (score 0):

Why `msg.d`? Where is `d`? As far as I can see, it should be `companies`. And the value is passed as second argument to the callback, see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(msg.companies, function(index, item) {
    options[options.length] = new Option(item.CompanyName, item.CompanyID);
});
```

Comment: this is where I get the d its in the response: "d":"{\"companies\" : [{\JSON.... I will try the suggestions and respond. Thanks.

Comment: @user684485: Well, you didn't post this. Then you might need `msg.d.companies`.

Comment: sorry for not fully explaining the POST response from Firebug. It is {"d":"{\"companies\" : [{\"CompanyID\" : \"5\",\"CompanyName\" : \"(No Insurance Carrier)\"},{\"CompanyID\" : \"0\",\"CompanyName\" : \"(None Specified)\"},{\"CompanyID\" : \"72431\",\"CompanyName\" : \"A.M. Technologies, Inc./W.P. Hickman Systems\"},{\"CompanyID\" : \"72486\",\"CompanyName\" : \"AAA\"},...]}"}  The “d” is a function of how ASP.NET AJAX returns JSON serialized data. The “d” acts as a container object

Comment: changing msg.d.companies breaks at companies

Comment: @user684485: Mmh. But you clearly have `d.companies` in the JSON string.